# Unexplained "Waiting" time ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, request

I'm facing a networking issue I can't explain on an ajax request. Here is the background :

My website has a lot of contact pages, in which we are gathering informations about a person on different social networks (twitter, linkedin, viadeo, google) and then we display it.

As this requires to send many ajax requests, we've decided to move some of them to JSONP and use some of our sub domains, so we don't reach the browser's limit of maximum request per domain.

So when a contact page loads, I have 7 JSONP requests sent (through subdomains), and 2 "real"  ajax request (meaning use of xhr object). Those 2 ajax requests both call the same PHP action "SocialTab" with differement parameters, and the other JSONP requests are calling distinct actions.

As we're experiencing speed issues on our contact pages, I've decided to monitor those requests, and realized that they can take ages to complete, it can take up to 15 seconds on some of them, with an average of 10 seconds. A deeper look at my SocialTab ajax requests with google network panel shows that almost 100% of the time is spent waiting a response from the server (cf screen).

[image]

Then I thought server side was the problem, so I commented out the PHP processing part, and do nothing else than a return. Result is the same, so the PHP part isn't responsible for that "Waiting" time the console tells me. How can it take up to 4 seconds of waiting if nothing is processed beyond ?

My last test was to remove my JSONP requests, and send only the SocialTab requests. Surprisingly, the waiting time is highly reduced, and makes more sense as you can see on the following screen.

[image]

Has anyone an explanation on this ?

NB : The website I'm making my test on is hosted on a server in my local network, and we're running under Symfony 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Found myself the answer. PHP session lock was the problem in case anyone wonders!

Comment: could you please tell me how you fix it, coz I'm facing the same issue with my App.